# Get the distinct elements from an array when comparing with another array, in liner time(without using collections)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

*INPUT*: 2 sorted arrays [Array `a` and Array `b`)

*OUPUT*: Elements in array `a` that are not in array `b`

**constraints**: linear time `without` the use of collections

This is my attempt thus far in Java:

```
static void findMissing(int a[], int b[], int n, int m) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
      if (a[i] == b[j])
        break;
      if (j == m)
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt does not use the condition that both array a and b are sorted, and that is why it is quadratic time. A linear solution needs two pointers i and j, i for array a and j for array b. Start from i = 0 and j = 0, compare a[i] and b[j].There are 3 cases to consider:

1. a[i] == b[j]: in this case, increment i and j by 1 since a[i] is in b.
2. a[i] < b[j]: since both arrays are sorted, and all elements that haven't been processed are equal to or bigger than b[j], we know that a[i] is not going to find a match. Increment i by 1.
3. a[i] > b[j]: similarly in this case, a[i] is not going to find a match from b[0] to b[j]. Increment j by 1.

If there are still unprocessed elements in a when all elements in b have been processed, output all these remaining elements in a as they are not in b.

Assuming you want to output duplicated elements multiple times if they don't exist in b, the following code implements this two pointer algorithm.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void findMissing(int[] a, int[] b, int n, int m) {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while(i < n && j < m) {
            if(a[i] == b[j]) {
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else if(a[i] < b[j]) {
                System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
                i++;
            }
            else {
                j++;
            }
        }
        while(i < n) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,3,5,7,8,9,10}, b = {3,5,7,9,11};
        findMissing(a, b, 7, 4);
    }
}
```

If you only want to output duplicated elements once, then each time i or j is advanced, check if the next element is the same with the previous one, if they are the same, keep incrementing until the adjacent elements are different or you reach the end of the array. All the rest logic stays the same.